# Action on Group Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, group-schemes

I have question which arises from the answer of my former thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324887/why-is-for-a-group-scheme-of-finite-type-smooth-resp-irreducible-equivale

Let $G/K$ be a group scheme of finite type. Fix the algebraic closure $\bar{K}$ of $K$ and consider the resulting Galois group ${\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$.

As @Piotr Achinger stated there exist an "canonical" action on $\bar G = G \otimes \bar{K}$ by ${\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$.

My question is what kind of action is here meant?

My two possible guesses/ candidates:

1. The action on "points" $\bar{G}(\bar{K})= Hom(Spec(\bar{K}), \bar{G})$ via composing $\phi \mapsto \phi \circ g$ for a $g \in {\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$

or

2. the action via "base change": namely that $g$ induces automorphism on $\bar{G}$ via $id⊗g$?

Which of these two is here considered?

Comment: Both. I mean 2. is the good definition, but 1. is the resulting action on $\overline{K}$-points.

Comment: I think you want to conjugate in 1., i.e. $\phi \mapsto g^{-1}\circ \phi \circ g$, instead of just composing?

Comment: @Notone: In 1. I mean that ${\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$ acts on $\bar{G}(\bar{K})= Hom(Spec(\bar{K}), \bar{G})$ as following: a $g \in {\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$ induces obviously an automorphism $g^a$ on  $Spec(\bar{K})$. The $g$ induced an automorphism on $\bar{G}(\bar{K})= Hom(Spec(\bar{K}), \bar{G})$ by "prefix" $g^a$ before a $\phi \in Hom(Spec(\bar{K}), \bar{G})$. I'm not sure what you mean here by "conjugation". Could you explain it a bit more? What is your $g^{-1}\circ \phi \circ g$?

Comment: To summarize, for $G=Spec(A)$ affine, we have an action of the Galois group on $G \times Spec(\overline{K})$ given on coordinate rings as you suggest. This will induce a map on the level of points $Hom(A \otimes \overline{K}, \overline{K})$ given by conjugation. However, you want an action on the whole scheme rather than just its points

Comment: @Notone: More precisely why composition $g^{-1}\circ \phi$ make sense? The domain and codomain don't coinside? Or how do you interpret this composition?

Comment: @leibnewtz: By action via "conjugation" on $Hom(A \otimes \overline{K}, \overline{K})$ you mean the "prefixing" of $id \otimes g$: therefore that $g$ induces automorpism on $Hom(A \otimes \overline{K}, \overline{K})$ via $\phi \mapsto \phi \circ (id \otimes g)$, right?

Comment: @leibnewtz: Additionally, yes I indend indeed to find out what is the action on whole scheme. Piotr explains in the linked thread that this "action" takes place only on the rough underlying topological space $\vert G \vert$. This is what I don't understand. Do you have an idea what he means?

Comment: It's an abuse of notation, both domain and codomain have an galois action. I think you want to conjugate to get a $\overline{K}$ morphism, as composition only gives a $K$ morphism. This is in Borel's Linear Algebraic Groups p.31

Comment: @Notone:Yes I guess I understand: If we reduce the problem to the action on $Hom(A \otimes \overline{K}, \overline{K})$ using leibnewtz' notation then your $g^{-1}\circ \phi \circ g$ is short notation for $g^{-1}\circ \phi \circ (id \otimes g)$, right?

Comment: @Notone:One point I don't understand: if $G$ is affine that this settles an acceptable action on $\bar{G}(\bar{K})= Hom(Spec(\bar{K}), \bar{G})$. What is if $G$ is not affine? Then we can define this action only locally on affine subspaces? And this can only be extended to whole $G$ if it can be covered by ${\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$-invariant affine open sets,right? Do you see how to settle this problem?

Comment: By the way: @Piotr Achinger explained in the linked thread that the action he had in mind didn't used really the scheme structure but works on the underlying topological space $\vert G \vert$. Does anybody know which action he means?

Comment: There is no need to retrict to the affine case as both galois maps are defined globally; is that your concern? (Also you are right in your previous comment).

Comment: @Notone:Yes it was one of my concerns. So the action on $\bar{G}(\bar{K})$ is clear now. The only still unsolved point is described in my last comment about the action on  the underlying topological space $\vert G \vert$ as explained in the linked thread. Indeed, $\bar{G}(\bar{K})$ is (topologically) a subset of $\vert G \vert$ but what about the action on whole $\vert G \vert$?